# Creating a modal previous and next interaction for images

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, modal-dialog

I am having trouble adding a functioning previous and next button to my modal windows to allow users to navigate through my images without clicking the X and finding the next image. Here is my website link to see and how everything is set out. http://monospaced.co.uk/

I have been struggling for months, my last test I managed to get the previous and next buttons, but they were sitting on the main page when i need them inside of the modal window for each image, and it wouldn't switch. Thanks, for taking the time to help. (if anyone does!)

I am a designer so while it's probably simple to create a previous and next button for your images inside a modal window, I am not sure how to do it without starting from scratch as I wouldn't understand what to change in my code without breaking the website.

Sorry I couldn't get the code into the question. I would really appreciate help, but I understand If it's too much effort because my question is trash...

Comment: See if you can get some of your code running in a jsfiddle. Also post the relevant code that you're running now so that we can see what you're trying and edit what you have

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle, i couldnt post all the code here as it said it was too much, i couldn't split it into 3 as it wouldn't run properly sorry. http://jsfiddle.net/kmybx67d/